# Calling UIViewController and never is deallocated

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

I've the class OTNetwork that is subclass of UIViewController.

When user pushes a button I use this code to call it:

```
OTNetwork *net = [[OTNetwork alloc] initWithNibName:@"OTNetwork" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:net animated:YES];

[net release];
```

When user wants to exit, pushes a button and the OTNetwork object sends a notification that makes the caller ViewController dismiss the view controller. This is the code:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

My problem is that the OTNetwork object dealloc method is never called. And here is the invalidate call to a timer that never is stopped. An aditional problem is the memory leak.

In the caller View Controller this object only is created and dismissed by these lines of code.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autorelease never guarantees when the dealloc will be called and you shouldn't rely on that.

And autorelease pools should be used for threads or when you have large memory allocations in a closed loop. It shouldn't be used on the main thread which already runs in a separate pool.

You should probably move the invalidate timer call to viewDidUnload or viewWillDisappear in OTNetwork class.

Hope that helps.

[Update: Mar 02, 2012]

If you'd like to ensure that dealloc is called, try the following

1) Store a reference to OTNetwork controller

```
OTNetwork *net = [[OTNetwork alloc] initWithNibName: @"OTNetwork" bundle: nil];
net.delegate = self;
self.modalV = net; // @property (nonatomic, strong) OTNetwork *modalV;
[net release];

[self presentModalViewController: modalV animated: YES];
```

2) Define a protocol / delegate in OTNetwork to report back when it's closed

```
// .h
@protocol OTNetworkDelegate;
    - (void) netViewClosed;
@end

// .m
- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    [self.delegate netViewClosed];
}
```

3) In mainViewController, implement the protocol

```
- (void) netViewClosed
{
    if(modalV)
    {
        [modalV release], modalV = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I have undestood, when a method creates an object and must return it, it have to be autorelease right? In this case how can I assume that will be released? By the caller of this method?

Comment: Object allocation and return is a different question. But yes, you can autorelease an object while returning from a function but make sure you retain it in the calling function. However, in the context of current question, if you want to ensure that dealloc is called, retain a reference to your "net" object and then release it manually when the viewcontroller closes. In order to know when the viewcontroller dismissed, you may need to setup a delegate to report back to the calling controller. I'm going to update my answer above to include how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

when you pass your OTNetwork object to the self which i'm assuming is a navigationController then your OTNetwork object is in the release pool and you don't need to worry about it being deallocated also cause your code is good on memory management.

So the short answer, its in the autorelease pool

Comment: Yes, I assumed this, but the problem is that the dealloc function never is called. And the program crashes because memory. :(

Comment: Maybe you're application is retaining or assigning that view controller in some other place and then its being released by the autorelease pool but accessed again by that class

Answer (score 1):

you can try this for dealloc to be called , by using your own autorelease pool.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
try{
//your code for allocating that object
 OTNetwork *net = [[[OTNetwork alloc] initWithNibName:@"OTNetwork" bundle:nil] autorelease]; [self presentModalViewController:net animated:YES];
}
finally{
[pool drain];
}
```